# gdal_merge on a three band .tif - remove the 'no data' value

Tags: gis, raster, gdal

I have a large set of .tif files and I need to merge/mosaic them all into one .tif with the no-data value removed (i.e. value 230, 245, 255).
However, when I put this in...pixel '230, 245, 255' becomes '0, 245, 255').

I am trying to get NO PIXEL returned for 230, 245, 255. Is that possible?

```
I:\TFS_6\trial_merge>gdal_merge.py -o test.tif -n 230 245 255 file1.tif file2.tif

ERROR 4: `245' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

ERROR 4: `255' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Comment: `-n` expects one value, not a list of values. Does each file have a single nodata value?

Comment: @MikeT no, it is a 3 - band pixel value I am trying to 'mask/remove'. So I tried 'gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata "230 245 255" tif_index.vrt *.tif' and got back a .vrt with Band 1 = 0 (instead of 230) and the full 3 Band value becoming (0 245 255)....not what I expected. I expected it to become "NoData"....

Answer (score 2):

```
gdalbuildvrt -addalpha -hidenodata -srcnodata "230 245 255" merged_tif.vrt *.tif
```

This turned the 'NoData' values into '230 245 255'...so I was able to filter BOTH 'NoData' and '230 245 255' accordingly,